# Jquery: function when select/otpion change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, onchange

nothing happens with this script.
Any advice ?
I just want to make an action when an option is selected.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#something').on('change', function() {
    console.log("hello");
})
</script>
```

```html
<form id="target" method="POST" >
    <select id="something"> 
        <option></option>
        <option>Value1</option>
        <option>Value2</option>
        <option>Value3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to fix your own code snippet. Maybe after it will work.

Comment: The snippet in your question doesn't work because you've put html in the JS window, but if that code were to be placed on a "normal" page it would work as long as the script elements were *after* the form. Either that or wrap your `.change()` handler code in a document ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```js
$('#something').on('change', function() {
    console.log("hello");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="target" method="POST" >
    <select id="something"> 
        <option></option>
        <option>Value1</option>
        <option>Value2</option>
        <option>Value3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

You have prepared wrong snippet. in script block it should be pure javascript and including js should be in html block. you have written in js block

Comment: You could at least explain your answer. Otherwise current comment is much better then this.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the code. Check this :)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#something').on('change', function() {
  alert(2);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target" method="POST">
  <select id="something"> 
        <option></option>
        <option>Value1</option>
        <option>Value2</option>
        <option>Value3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<title>Test</title>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="target" method="POST" >
    <select id="something"> 
        <option></option>
        <option>Value1</option>
        <option>Value2</option>
        <option>Value3</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>

<script>
$('#something').change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
</script>
</html>
```